# Cambiar tamaño de imagen tomada con cámara, Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Necesito cambiar el tamaño de una imagen capturada con la cámara, `dataImage` parece ser la que otorga el tamaño de la imagen, este es mi código:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

        var capturedImage = UIImage(data: dataImage)

        let cameraPosition = currentVideoInput?.device.position



        if let image = capturedImage, cameraPosition == .front {

            capturedImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored)

            self.tempImageView.image = capturedImage


        } else if let image = capturedImage, cameraPosition == .back {

            capturedImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

            // Código

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(capturedImage!)
        }
    }
}
```

En `print(capturedImage!)` puedo ver que el tamaño de la imagen tomada es de 720 x 1280. Quisiera que el tamaño fuera de 1280 x 1280. ¿Cómo logro hacer esto?

Comment: quieres cambiar el tamaño una vez tomada la foto? o cambiar la resolucion de las fotos que vas a sacar?

Comment: Cambiar la resolución de la foto que voy a sacar.